# RoR: Displaying index page using "root" in routing file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my very first app that I'm running in RoR. This is the template **app/views/home/index.html.erb**. It contains this

```
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
```

My controller is **app/controllers/home_controllers.rb**. But the class inside the file is Home

```
Home < ActionController::Base
   def index
   end
end
```

Finally, here is my routing file

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
   root :to => 'Home#index'
end
```

When I am running this application, I'm getting the following error: "**Routing Error: No route matches [GET] "/"**"

What's wrong with my application?

## EDIT

After applying all the corrections, this is how it looks.

```
HomeController < ActionController:: Base
   def index
   end
end
```

And the routing is now

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
   root :to => 'Home#index'
end
```

I've also restarted the server, but I'm still getting the same error.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the pluralization, `home_controllers` should be `home_controller`. In addition name your class `HomeController` instead of `Home`.

Comment: Is a controller supposed to be a class? Does it supposed to start with a capital letter?

Comment: Class name yes, filename no. So `HomeController` and `home_controller`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `HomeController` instead of `Home`.

Comment: Controllers with s or without?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
   root :to => 'home#index'
```

Comment: This is what run me a little crazy. They said ruby is case sensitive, but why the name of the class is HomeController, but in the routing home is small case?

Comment: and don't forget to `restart your server` after updating `routes.rb`

Comment: `Home` versus `home` in this instance should not matter.